# Cache issue on component renderings

Tags: sxa, caching

Cache from Site settings is already set, but on Renderings level, the cache is enabled. which shows the same content of the component on the page it cached.

For example:

There are 3 promos on the page (About, Services and Contact), and cache is set on promos from `/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Page Content/Promo`

The About promo shows fine but services and contact shows the same as the About promo. It also caches the CSS classes as well. Did anyone face the same issue?

Am using Sitecore 8.2 Update 3

Comment: Are there any reasons why the cache is set on the rendering and not on the component? I mean when you set on the rendering you are caching the rendering per say and not the component instance

Comment: to reduce the time, obviously. the website is far too big to apply the cache one by one. and we can not completely set the cache on all the components

Comment: If it makes sense you can user Sitecore powershell to set for you the cache with a simple script like this
https://sitecorebrasil.wordpress.com/2017/04/28/updating-renderings-properties-using-sitecore-powershell-extensions/

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust Caching settings a bit to "Vary by Data" also:

[image]

Take a look here for further information:
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/setting_up/set_sxa_caching_options

Comment: I tried it, and it works but on certain points it causes the issue. Let me test it again on different devices. thnx

Comment: What do you mean by certain points?

Comment: I mean the issue is random. and replicates on some pages and not overall the website

Comment: Try maybe also 'Vary by query string' and 'Vary by parm'. Try maybe increase cache size in config

Comment: already set the high size of cache in config.

Comment: Do you have a load balancer and users are seeing cache from different servers?